# What damage type do Daybreak Arrows have when fired from enhanced weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage-types

My paladin is wielding a bow as his bonded weapon. Using Divine Bond, he enhances his bow with *flaming burst*. Now his attacks are rolled like this:

- 1d8 piercing damage
- 1d6 fire damage (and an additional 1d10 fire damage on crits)

Now he casts *[Daybreak Arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/daybreak-arrow)* on his quiver.

> Undead and creatures harmed by sunlight take an additional 1d6 points of damage from such projectiles. This extra damage **and half of any other damage you deal with an affected projectile results directly from radiant energy** and is not subject to damage resistance.

Emphasis mine.

So, let's say I hit, and roll:

- 5 piercing damage
- 4 fire damage
- 3 radiant damage

Does the *Daybreak Arrow* change only the projectile's own damage (5 piercing damage) or also apply to the fire damage (which is technically originating from the same projectile, but is because the bow is enhanced)?

So, does it become:

- 3 piercing damage (-2)
- 2 fire damage (-2)
- 7 radiant damage (+4)

or;

- 3 piercing damage (-2)
- 4 fire damage
- 5 radiant damage (+2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### All damage types are converted to radiant.

Any *other source* damage outside of that **extra 1d6** becomes *radiant type* damage and ignores damage reduction from undeads.

So, if you fire an arrow with 1d8 (piercing) + 1d10 (fire) + 1d6 (from daybreak), you cause 1d6 + half the result of 1d8+1d10 as radiant damage, the remaining damage is still their original types (piercing and fire).

Comment: When rounding, do you round in favor of radiant damage?

Comment: Unless said otherwise, you *always round down in Pathfinder*.

Answer (score 0):

Because Daybreak Arrow specifies "*any* damage", it would take half the arrow's damage and half the flaming damage to convert into Radiant. This is also supported by the other sources of Radiant damage, such as [Flame Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-strike), that deal partial Energy and partial Radiant damage.

A better answer might include what happens if you deal 3 damage with the arrow and 3 more damage with the Flaming; I'm not sure if it would be

- 2 piercing
- 2 fire
- +2 radiant

or

- 3 total piercing and fire
- +3 radiant

I would tend toward the first because they're different sources of damage, but I'm not sure if/where there is a rule to govern halving multiple types of damage.

Comment: In my question, I round down the radiant portion (5 piercing becomes 3 piercing and 2 radiant). In your answer, you seem to suggest that the radiant portion is rounded up. Can you clarify and have a source for doing this?

Comment: Because the weapon special ability *flaming* deals *extra* damage, effects are applied to that extra damage separately. (See [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67608/8610) as to why this is sometimes important.)

Comment: @MarcDingena No, I jut typed too fast. It would be rounded down, editing.